# Total amount doesnt show from Shopping Cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, paypal, shopping-cart

**Background Story:** Shopping Cart wont display Total and Cart Total! I got the code via http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL442E340A42191003 and i did some modification.

**Here is the image view of the problem:** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xGRT.jpg

**What i did to debug:** I tried to debug by echoing variables for testing to make sure the variables stored is of right value

Total (Individual Product) and Cart Total needs to be derived from
 **$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];**

I debug by testing echo **$price** and echo **$each_item['quantity']** Both showed the right value in it. However to my surprise, echo **$pricetotal** showed result of $0.00! I then moved on to changing **$pricetotal = $price + $each_item['quantity'];** In this case, by echoing **$pricetotal** , i got the value of 2. (2 quantity) and the total/Cart total became $2.00.

---

**Conclusion from the experiment:**

- Individual echoing of **$price** and **$each_item['quantity']**
  showed right.
- echoing **$pricetotal** only gave    **$each_item['quantity']** and
  no value of **$price** existed.

On the other hand, the PayPal checkout button works and PayPal is able to obtain the product amount,quantity and Total.

May i know what is wrong??

Here are the code for reference:

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "MyOnlineStore/storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 2 (if user chooses to empty their shopping cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {                  
    // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com">';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bag WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["title"];
            $price = $row["cprice"];
            $details = $row["description"];
            $image = $row["image"];
        }                                   
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/' . $image . '" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>$' . $price . '</td>';

        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';

    //  $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    } 
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
    $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
    $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : ".$cartTotal." SGD</div>";
    // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.yoursite.com/storescripts/my_ipn.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.yoursite.com/checkout_complete.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.yoursite.com/paypal_cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="SG">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SGD">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
    </form>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Homepage - Bagnista</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>

  <body>
    <?php 
if (empty($_SESSION['user']))
 {
 include_once("header.php");
 }
else     {
      include_once("header2.php");
      }?>

<div class="page-header">

  <div class="container">


    <br />
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="18%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product</strong></td>
        <td width="45%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product Description</strong></td>
        <td width="10%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Remove</strong></td>
      </tr>
     <?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
     <!-- <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr> -->
    </table>
    <?php echo $cartTotal; ?>
    <br />
<br />
<?php echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?>
    <br />
    <br />
     <a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Click here to empty Shopping Cart!</button</a>



    </div>      
   <br />     <? echo  $pricetotal?>   // code for debugging purpose
  </div>
  <?php include_once("footer.php");?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>        
</html>
```

Comment: what did you get when echoing the price variable, I mean in what format and type exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this:

```
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
```

with:

```
$pricetotal = floatval(str_replace('$','',$price)) * $each_item['quantity'];
```

Comment: IT WORKSSSSSSSSSSSS IT WORKSSSSSSSSSS THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I  APPRECIATED IT FROM THE BOTTOM OF MY HEART!

Comment: you are welcome but this is a dirty solution, you should store prices in the database without the dollar sign you should fix that later by changing the column type from var_char to float and strip the dollar sign before storing, then your code will work without the need of str_replace, anyway this will work for now but consider fixing it later.

Comment: i have found that using field type decimal(5,2) seems to work too.